# Implementation of google map in android application

Tags: android-manifest

While i am trying to extend my class to MapActivity it is show error like "no suggestion available" i had installed all the google apis, any body has the idea please help me Mithun

Comment: Your question is too vague. Show relevant pieces of code, what exact result you are getting and what result you are expecting.

Comment: Actually my question is,for implementing Google map in an android  application which version of android sdk should select , me selected sdk version of 2.3.3 , while selecting this the code is getting error when extending the MapActivity instead of Activity,after this me selected Google Api version at  that time the code is not getting any error, but can not launch the virtual Device while trying to launch it i'm getting a pop up message like no compactable device available,or can you please suggest me the least version of android sdk,which support Google maps

Comment: Don't update the question in comments. Update it by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

To use google map select google api sdk of version (your choice). Only after that you can use google map. I think you have used "Android x.x Api x.x" during project setup.

Rather choose Google APIs version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Google's page with instructions for installing the APIs Add-On using the *Android SDK and AVD Manager* tool:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing.html